# Is there a way to access a function's attributes/parameters within a ContextDecorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, contextmanager

I'm trying to write a context manager decorator using Python's contextlib.ContextDecorator class.

Is there a way to access the decorated function's parameters within the context manager?

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator

class savePen(ContextDecorator):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.prevPen = self.dc.GetPen()     # AttributeError
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        self.dc.SetPen(self.prevPen)
        return False
```

Given the above, this:

```
@savePen()
def func(dc, param1, param2):
    # do stuff, possibly changing the pen style
```

should be equivalent to:

```
def func(dc, param1, param2):
    prevPen = dc.GetPen()
    # do stuff, possibly changing the pen style
    dc.SetPen(prevPen)
```

---

I've scoured the docs for [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html) and haven't found anything useful.

Does anyone know how to access the decorated functions' attributes from within a ContextDecorator class?

#### EDIT1:

As @chepner said in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732658/1354930), ContextDecorator is sugar for

```
def func(dc, param1, param2):
    with savePen():
        ...
```

and that it cannot access the functions' parameters.

However, in this case, whatever runs inside of `with savePen()` has access to the function parameters `dc`, `param1`, and `param2`. This makes me think that I should be able to access them using ContextDecorator.

For example, this is valid:

```
def func(dc, param1, param2):
    with savePen():
        print(param1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contextlib.contextmanager` seems more appropriate here. Note that, like anything else, you can't access the local variables of a function body from outside the function (short of introspection hacks, anyway).

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def savePen(dc):
    prevPen = dc.GetPen()
    yield
    dc.SetPen(prevPen)

with savePen(dc):
    func(dc, param1, param2)
```

Note that with a `ContextDecorator`, the context manager is instantiated with no arguments, that is

```
@savePen()
def func(dc, param1, param2):
    # do stuff, possibly changing the pen style
```

is syntactic sugar (according to the documentation) for

```
def func(dc, param1, param2):
    with savePen():
        ...
```

and so there's no way to tell `savePen` which object (`dc`) to work with.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I guess it's not a big deal to have two functions/classes defined, but it would have been nice to have just the one. I'll try it out and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: If ContextDecorator is just syntactic sugar for `def ... with ...`, then it *should* be able to access the func's parameters, right? See my edit for a little more detail.

Comment: Python uses static scoping; `savePen` only has access to variables in the lexical scope where it is defined, not the scope where it is called. (And even then, you would need Python 3's `nonlocal` keyword to modify them. Here, that's not an issue because you are just invoking methods on a referenced object.)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by building my own decorator, using stuff I'd done before in Python2.

Instead of using a context manager I simply used a `try...finally` structure.

Here's what I came up with (I've removed all the fluff that does things like make docstrings correct):

```
class savePen(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """This provides support for functions """
        dc = args[0]
        prevPen = dc.GetPen()
        try:
            retval =  self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            dc.SetPen(prevPen)
        return retval

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        """ And this provides support for instance methods """
        @functools.wraps(self.func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            dc = args[0]
            prevPen = dc.GetPen()
            try:
                retval = self.func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                dc.SetPen(prevPen)
            return retval
        return wrapper
```